# Problem with unwanted mobile layout in Google Chrome!

Tags: support, design

When I open this site on Google Chrome, it looks like :

**Mobile and Tablet Layout**

[image]

But works fine on Firefox.

All other stackexchange sites works fine on both Chrome and Firefox.

**P.S:**

I'm using Linux Ubuntu + Gnome Shell

Comment: Are you sure this is the mobile layout? How did you select that?

Comment: I think so. I didn't select that!

Comment: I read your question as that you **wanted** the mobile layout, instead of that think you got it, without wanting it.

Comment: I'm running that on Linux machine but it has mobile layout!! I don't want mobile layout on my Linux machine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scroll to the bottom and click "full site".